# How can I reference a variable in a PHP file from another one?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have another problem, now I have variables in a PHP file that have to be referenced in another one, but it is doing it without success.

For further explanation, I have this segment in a PHP file:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['login']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']))
    establishingConnection($_REQUEST['login'], $_REQUEST['password'], $xml);
```

Here, I must submit a username and a password to establish a connection with a web service that I'm developing.

After that, the user can make operations like add/remove/change links/tags, and so on.. He can change his personal data (username, password, email or remove his own account). For any of those operations, I need the current login (i.e, his username). Like in this example:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
    if (isset($_REQUEST['password']) && isset($_REQUEST['newUsername']))
        changeUsername($_SESSION['login'], $_REQUEST['password'], $_REQUEST['newUsername'], $xml);
    else {
        $msg = 'Some fields are missing';
        message($xml, $msg, 1);
    }
}
else
{
    $msg = 'Please login first!';
    message($xml, $msg, 1);
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't import the login data properly. I can see this problem, by seeing this message:

```
$msg = 'Some fields are missing';
```

My main objective is to reference a PHP variable in a file, on another one. My JavaScript file is not responsible to provide th login's username. I tried to include php files, but without success.

Any suggestions to resolve this?

EDIT: Well, I tried on my php, but I figured out some problems in my JavaScript script.

I will post the functions that are responsible for this operation, since I don't have a clue where the problem is.

HTML:

```
        <div id="changeUserid">
            <form id="changeUseridForm">
                New username: <input type="text" id="newUserid" />
                <br>
                Type your password to validate your action: <input type="password" id="retypePass" />
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Change" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

My JavaScript (jQuery) function:

```
$("#changeUseridForm").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "API/root/users/changeUsername.php",
            data: {
            newUsername: $("#newUserid", this).val(),
            password: $("#retypePass", this).val(),
            xml: 1,
            },
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function(xml){
                if($(xml).find("success").length > 0){
                    alert("Username changed successfully!");
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                else if($(xml).find("error").length > 0){
                    alert("You have to fill all the fields!");
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

EDIT2: My problem in changing the username is solved. Now, I have the problem that I can make a login with a old username with success. Any suggestion?

Comment: You should start using way more curly braces, this code is bound to break. in the near future.

Comment: poor formatting, hard to read the code

Comment: I tried to format the best I could on this text editor. Unfortunately, I can't use tab, otherwise it jumps to the next HTML object. Copy and paste from the original doc doesn't always get the right formatting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I am completely understand your problem, are both these code segments from same file or separate ones? And are you submitting two different html forms or is it just one form?

I am assuming, you have submitted a HTML form to one page, and then when you move to another page, you want to access those same values, is that right? You can't pass the $_REQUEST values from one page to another like this. You can either assign these values to some variable and then include that file, or use session variables to store these files:

Do this in first file:

```
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$newUsername = $_REQUEST['newUsername'];
```

Then, include the first file in second one and use the variables (assuming first file is a.php):

```
include "a.php";
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    if (isset($password) && isset($newUsername)){
        changeUsername($_SESSION['login'], $password, $newUsername, $xml);
    } else {
        $msg = 'Some fields are missing';
        message($xml, $msg, 1);
    }
}
```

You can also use session variables to pass on data from one page to another, just make sure there is `session_start()` on start of every page you use session variables on.

Note: You should also validate user submitted data before using it, but that is another topic. Also, whenever in doubt, print/echo your variables to see what data is passing on and which variable is the problem.

EDIT (Question 2): Can you login from both new and old username? If yes, it means instead of replacing the currenct username for new one, you are adding a new user(name). Share how you are updaing the account info (that is, if you are using database, share the update query you are using) and someone might be able to help.

Comment: The first code segment isn't in the same file as the second fragment.

Ok, I tried to make an include, but I returns a fatal error, because it tries to connect to the database, every time I run any script. I commentated it, but it returns the same problematic result.

Comment: Whenever you include a PHP file, all the code in it is executed (except for functions and code in Classes), so just including a file to get it's variable is usually not a good idea. Try using sessions.

Comment: Like, making a `session_start()`? But I already do that at the beginning of the script.

After that, I have created my functions, to execute the sessions.

Comment: Ok, I figured out my problem.. It's from my JavaScript, which it doesn't send his data.. Thanks! :)

Comment: I figured out my problem.. The PHP fragment missed curly braces..

However, I can still make a login with the oldUsername. Any suggestions to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to Session_start(). Please make sure that you have included this before checking the session login and password variables.